# How to make a specific text ignore columns

Tags: templates, columns, alignment

I found a template online, its good but I want to change the part where it says "Research Experience"

[image: ![enter image description here]

I want it to be in one line instead of one under the other. I am very new to latex and couldn't find how to do it in the template. here is the code

```
\section{\Large{Research Experience}}

\vspace{30pt}
\section{\rightline{Oct 2018 - }}
\textsf{\textbf{Parallel Hashing}}, \textit{Program for Undergraduate Research}, Sabanci University\\[-27pt]
\section{\rightline{Present }}
Parallelizing City Hashing,MurMur Hashing,Tabulation Hashing algorithms
with\\SIMD instructions, improving their performance.
```

I just need to make it ignore the columns for that specific line. How can I do that?

There is the link to the template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/recent-grad-resume-template/gjxncvsftpqr .

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the community with a reference to the template you found. There might be better ways of resolving your issue. Also, it can help others find this post more easily. Do you have a link to the template?

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/recent-grad-resume-template/gjxncvsftpqr here it is. Thank you.

Comment: Werners solution worked

Answer (score 1):

It should be sufficient to use

```
\section
  [Research Experience] % ToC entry
  {\makebox[0pt][l]{\Large Research Experience}} % Text entry
```

which allows for setting the sectional unit within the ToC as well (doubt there is one in what seems to be a resume/CV). The `\makebox[0pt][l]` construction sets the title inside a zero-width box that is left-aligned, allowing it to stretch as far right as needed without interfering with the margins/columns.

If you want some consistency in terms of formatting, don't include font-related macros as part of sectional units (your `\Large`). Instead, (re)define `\section` to always use/add that, taking care not to impede functionality with the ToC entries (you obviously don't want `\Large` to migrate to the ToC as well).